# Code to capture what php files are being used to render my Web page

Tags: php, debugging, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to determine what php files are used on the pages on my Web site, Wordpress with Woocommerce. I leveraged this code to capture the associated php file names in an html comment on the page that I could inspect. This code seemed to work, but maybe too well.  On a pretty basic page on my site the comment generated listed 1,827 different php files.  Does it really go through that many files to generate a single Web page?  Is there something wrong with this code? Or is there a way to narrow the output file names to the main ones that define the page functionality?

```
<?php echo '<!--'; // you can display this code or show it in an HTML comment
$files = get_included_files();
if ($display_only_theme_files === true) {
  $theme_folder = get_template_directory();
  foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    if (strstr($file, $theme_folder) === false) {
      unset($files[$key]);
    }
  }
}
print_r($files);
echo '-->'; // you can display this code or show it in an HTML comment
?>
```

Comment: On a Wordpress site? Yeah, that doesn't sound too far off. Wordpress is notoriously bloated. Tack on a heavy plugin like WooCommerce, and you've got yourself a pretty hefty backtrace of inclusions.

Comment: To answer your latter question, it depends on what you're attempting to debug. [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Generic_Profiler_ad&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIprL79cn26QIVCEmGCh0RFA9zEAAYASAAEgJAavD_BwE) is pretty good about indicating heavy processes, where they're coming from, and the order in which it happens. But you might want to look into a good IDE that supports breakpoints (I use PHPStorm) and enabling XDebug to figure out the flow of your code.

Comment: Xdebug is a good option. Ugliest way is to throw an exception on the last file that gets executed or call an undefined function in it to see if it throws a stack trace.